# Is it possible to force a PHP stylesheet import to ignore a string?

Tags: php, css, import

I'd like to import a PHP stylesheet (style.php) into my HTML doc. Is it possible to remove certain strings from style.php, and then import it using conventional methods (like `<link>`)? I'd like to remove `<style>` tags specifically.

Comment: So just to understand, you are putting invalid code in your styles file in order to get the proper syntax highlighting in your editor software, and now you want a way to ignore that when the style sheet is needed? My advice is to get a better editor (I use phpDesigner 8). What you have described is not good (or even tolerable) practice - and should make everyone who reads this slightly sad. :)

Comment: I've already emailed the Coda guys to see whether there's an existing syntax library that will highlight CSS within a PHP doc without having to open style tags - I'm more interested in whether or not there's a way to do this or not. Like forcing a script to ignore a string that matches certain parameters

Comment: You're tweaking your code to satisfy your IDE. That's just silly. :)

Comment: haha probably but I'm being impatient - don't want to wait for an answer from the support kids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File "css.php" which includes style.php file that contains your CSS

```
ob_start();

require("style.php"); 

$css = ob_get_clean();

$css = str_replace(array("<style>","</style>"),array("",""),$css);

echo $css;
```

Include this in the main page
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php" type="text/css" media="screen" />`

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many choice here. You will need include the file as a file, leaving `<style></style>` in-place instead of a linked stylesheet. This, of course, breaks the browser's ability to cache the file so it will have to be served up with every page.

It seems like a bad work-around just to get some syntax highlighting.

Comment: So is there no PHP method to alter a file before import? Something like `str_replace`, then echo out `<link href="/style.php">` to the edited file

Comment: Why not just choose a better editor? Or paste in into one that works, edit it and paste it back.

Comment: the editor works perfectly for web dev on osx, and there's no way that pasting in and out is a solution.